# Get "home/index" in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After running `rails generate controller home index` in my Rails application, I see this line in `routes.rb`

```
get "home/index"
```

What does this line do? When I removed it, I didn't observe any difference it makes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) page for more info but...

It adds, to the routing table, an entry to direct a `GET` request of the form

```
http://localhost:3000/home/index
```

To the `HomeController#index` action, which will render a response and display the results to the user.

It is a shorthand notation for

```
match 'home/index' => 'home#index', :via => :get
```

To see what other routes your application has available, run the following from a terminal while inside your projects directory

```
rake routes
```